# How convert delegate to byte array?

Tags: c#, .net

How convert delegate (Func) to byte array?

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect a `byte[]` to mean here?

Note that you can serialize delegates with `BinaryFormatter`, but that is also serialinh the delegate's target instance etc.

But something like:

```
byte[] raw;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(ms, yourDelegate);
    raw = ms.ToArray();
}
// use raw somewhere
```

Note that how *useful* this is depends on your specific scenario.